# autoresig control is not working as behavior in iOS-8

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, autoresize

I am taking new view controller in Old application and disabled there size class to use autoresize control .

Intial XIB is based on : **iPhone 4 inch** (iPhone-5) and i want to resize for **iPhone-3.5 inch**  (iPhone-4).

I am using controller as usually : given below :

[image]

But view is not going up-side .

Controls are not working at all . Not-even in any condition .